# Google Cloud Run route traffic to a specific domain using static IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run service, which sends requests to a number of domains:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com

domain3.com requires that all my requests are coming from the same static IP address
Is this possible to do so in cloud run?

I've found a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) on how to set up static outbound IP address.  But I don't really understand whether it is possible to do that only for one specific domain.

If I understand correctly, it should be done (if possible) somewhere on the `Cloud NAT` level.
Also, I guess that I would need to first "explore" an IP address of the `domain3.com` in order to use that address in Cloud NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a Cloud Run service, you can't use a specific IP to reach only one domain and not the others.

On a Cloud Run service, you can plug a serverless VPC connector to route `all` the traffic in that connector (I assume that your domain.com are public domain, therefore the `all` parameter for the egress), and add a Cloud NAT to use your reserved IP(s). ([here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) in the documentation)

Because you route **ALL** the traffic, you can't select for that domain (or IP) and not this one. It's ALL!

Comment: Yes, `domain.com` are public domains.